# contenteditable inside div is main

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

When I put a div in it contenteditable I want the first thing the user writes to create a div that is basic and not deleted and the text is inside the div

I do not like this :

[image]

I like this :

[image]

Even if the user deletes everything, there remains a div that he writes inside

Comment: In order to add a style when it clicks on, for example (textCenter), I put it on this div

Comment: Why can't you set `text-align: center` on the contenteditable itself?

Answer (score 0):

This function can help you to add an **EventListener (double click)** to the desired **div**.

Once it is double clicked, it will disable the trigger function and add all the content into an **Input** type element to be edited.

The editing will be finished if the user presses Enter or FocusOut the element, causing that all its value goes into the original parent **div** and add the **editThis** function once again.

Note: I recommend adding a minimum width to the parent **div** so it can be double clickable at all this.

```
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("dblclick", editThis);

function editThis() {
    this.removeEventListener("dblclick", editThis)
    var triggerElement = this
    var content = this.textContent;

    this.innerHTML = `<input type="text" id="editing" value="${content}">`;
    document.getElementById("editing").focus();
    document.getElementById("editing").addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
        if (e.key != "Enter") return;
        var newValue = document.getElementById("editing").value;

        triggerElement.innerHTML = "";
        triggerElement.textContent = newValue;
        triggerElement.addEventListener("dblclick", editThis);
    })
    document.getElementById("editing").addEventListener("focusout", (e) => {
        var value = document.getElementById("editing").value;
        triggerElement.innerHTML = "";
        triggerElement.textContent = newValue;
        triggerElement.addEventListener("dblclick", editThis);
    })
}
```